# Count the cells corresponding to lookup value

Tags: excel

I want my excel function to do the following actions on the below attached spreadsheet image:

1. Search for SumA in Column B
2. Every time the system finds SumA, count of cells which has text = “ Not Started” for Day 0 under K2 corresponding to the SumA
3. Display the total count

Note: There are merged cells in column B.

[image: Excel Spreadsheet]

Comment: So what is your question and what have you tried so far?

Comment: Does `CountIfs()` not work?

Comment: COUNTIF('B5:B40,INDEX(B5:B40,MATCH("SumA",'B5:H40,0)))

Comment: I don't know how to retrieve count when the system finds SumA under columnB

Comment: @VBAPete- =COUNTIFS(B5:B40,"SumA", J5:J40," Not Started"). here is what is tried but it is not working

Comment: Should be working, does it matter that some say "SumA" and others "Sum A", check there are no trailing spaces etc `=COUNTIFS(B5:B40,"*SumA*", J5:J40,"*Not Started*")` You have a trailing space in your second criteria " Not Started".

Comment: Thanks @TimWilkinson - I appreciate your help. I've removed the trailing spaces and it works